# Slick carousel slides are sticking to eachother and the images are not shown properly

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

So i got this slider , and my slider must show 4 slides , but when i give padding to the slides , the images start to dissapear and my slider looks broken[this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L37ca.png)

here is my code :
HTML

```
<div class="partners">
          <div class="partners__slider">
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner1.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner2.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner3.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner4.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner1.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner2.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner3.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="partners__slider--item">
              <img src="./assets/images/partner4.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS :

```
.partners {
  margin-top: 200px;
  &__slider {
    &--item {
      padding: 39px 89px;
      background-color: #fafafa;
      img {
        max-width: 290px;
        max-height: 120px;
      }
    }
}
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".partners__slider").slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    nextArrow: "<img class='slick-next' src='./assets/images/next.png'>",
    prevArrow: "<img class='slick-prev' src='./assets/images/previous.png'>",
  });
});
```

this is what the slider should look like :
[the slider according to the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RayD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have the padding flipped. The example you're trying to replicate has more vertical padding than horizontal.

Trying changing your &--item padding to

```
padding: 89px 39px;
```

You might also have to adjust the image dimensions. You could try something like the below example, or manually adjust the width and height to preference.

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested , and now it looks much better , but there is still one problem .
[link] (https://imgur.com/a/5aaQVxI). the background of the slides are still stuck together, any suggestions ?

Comment: and the height of some slides differ from the others...

Comment: You can add something like margin-right: 10px; to  .partners__slider--item. If you want the height of the slides to be the same, you will want to either make the content all the same dimensions or add a fixed height to the slides or .partners__slider.